# Keystone error with Devstack

Tags: openstack, keystone

I have followed [this](http://devstack.org/guides/single-vm.html) link to deploy devstack on my virtual machine. When I execute ./stack.sh script in the VM, I get the following error after sometime:

```
keystone endpoint-create: error: argument --service-id/--service_id: expected one argument
++ failed
++ local r=2
+++ jobs -p
++ kill
++ set +o xtrace
```

The script terminates without giving any information such as the host on which to access Horizon and the time elapsed in running the script. I am using NAT as my virtual machine network configuration since I am not able to connect to my network using bridge mode.

I get no response when trying to access Horizon from my web browser. When I try to execute stack.sh (not preceded by ./unstack.sh), I get the error that stack is already running. Please note that I am behind a proxy server and this is my network configuration on host and guest machines respectively:

**Host Machine:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d4:be:d9:7f:b3:6f  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:110688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:110688 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:6738439 (6.7 MB)  TX bytes:6738439 (6.7 MB)

vmnet1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:01  
          inet addr:172.16.85.1  Bcast:172.16.85.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:83 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:c0:00:08  
          inet addr:172.16.145.1  Bcast:172.16.145.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::250:56ff:fec0:8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:602 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:82 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:36:dd:3e:99:e6  
          inet addr:10.99.19.21  Bcast:10.99.19.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6236:ddff:fe3e:99e6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:215802 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:222520 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:245659430 (245.6 MB)  TX bytes:30196677 (30.1 MB)
```

**Guest Machine (Bridge):**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:8a:c9:d4  
          inet addr:172.16.145.128  Bcast:172.16.145.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:fe8a:c9d4/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1965 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1508 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2229981 (2.2 MB)  TX bytes:160543 (160.5 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2024 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:485 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:485 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:36153 (36.1 KB)  TX bytes:36153 (36.1 KB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 2e:32:9b:c3:f4:12  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

**My localrc file is configured like this:**

```
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.1.224/27
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
FLAT_INTERFACE=eth0
ADMIN_PASSWORD=password
MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
RABBIT_PASSWORD=password
SERVICE_PASSWORD=password
SERVICE_TOKEN=tokentoken
```

Please note that I am behind a proxy server. Googling this error returned me some pages that suggest that the issue can be solved by setting the 'no_proxy' variable with the main IP address of the devstack machine.

**Links to pages:**

https://bugs.launchpad.net/devstack/+bug/1015705
https://answers.launchpad.net/devstack/+question/219539

I don't know where to add these settings or how to solve this whole keystone error. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your VM IP to the no_proxy variable. In Below snippet, 10.0.2.15 is my devstack VM IP. To be permanently exported when starting your terminal, you can add the below line in /etc/bash.bashrc file.

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,10.0.2.15
```